# Property hiding and reflection (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, inheritance

Declaring a property in a derived class that matches the name of a property in the base class "hides" it (unless it overrides it with the `override` keyword).  Both the base and derived class properties will be returned by `Type.GetProperties()` if their types don't match.  However, if their types *do* match, shockingly only the derived class's property is returned.  For instance:

```
class A
{
    protected double p;
    public int P { get { return (int)p; } set { p = value; } }
}
class B : A
{
    public new int P { get { return (int)p; } set { p = value; } }
}
class C : B
{
    public new float P { get { return (float)p; } set { p = value; } }
}
```

Calling `typeof(C).GetProperties()` will only return B.P and C.P.  Is it possible to call `GetProperties()` in a way that returns all three?  There is almost certainly a way to do it by traversing the inheritance hierarchy, but is there a cleaner solution?

Comment: Why would you want to have such a class hierarchy ?

Comment: @driis: This is just a trivial example to illustrate.  But, for the sake of the argument, assume this class hierarchy is written by someone other than me, but I still need to find all of its public properties, even the hidden ones.

Comment: As there is no way that using the derived class you can access the hidden property I would suppose that effectively it does not have that property for Reflection. Consider yourself lucky, VB only shows C.P when using Shadows.

Comment: @Wilhelm: But you can access the hidden property: C c = new C(); ((A)c).P = 42;

Comment: Have you tried using BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy?  That said, not returning the property sounds like the correct behavior, as it's probably been hidden for a reason.

Comment: @Dan: FlattenHierarchy is for static members, it won't work here.

Comment: I like both answers so far pretty well.  I've decided to post a bounty and give it some more time to see if anyone can improve upon them since they each have a significant drawback.  It is interesting that neither fields nor methods have this problem with reflection.  Some satisfying explanation for this problem might also be an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GetProperties is defined as all public properties of the type.

You could get their get and set methods using:

```
typeof(C).GetMethods()
         .Where(m => m.Name.StartsWith("set_") || m.Name.StartsWith("get_"))
```

Although this seems like a bad idea, compared to going down the inheritance hierarchy to get the properties.

Comment: Then you would have the same problem with the get_P method hiding the one of the parent, I think.

Comment: @Yuriy: typeof(C).GetMethods().Where
@driis: No, it seems to work properly.

Comment: You are right. This method also works. Not quite sure why it works, since I assume the same method hiding rules go for methods as well as properties. Hmm.

Comment: This would work for me if I could get at the PropertyInfo from the getter or setter.

Comment: What do you need from the PropertyInfo that is not provided by the getter and setter?

Comment: I suppose it would work without the PropertyInfo, but I would have to be able to effectively match each getter with its respective setter, and that seems messy.

Comment: It's not quite clean, but this is the *only* method so far that really returns exactly the right number of properties.  Therefore, it is my accepted answer.  It it still just amazing to me that reflection can work so well will fields and methods, but fall flat on its face with properties.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think it is possible without traversing the inheritance hierarchy. It does not have to be too much code, though:

```
    public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetAllProperties(Type t)
    {
        while (t != typeof(object))
        {
            foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
                yield return prop;
            t = t.BaseType;
        }
    }
```

Of course, if you know a common basetype you can stop at, instead of object, it will be more efficient. Also; it will take some time to do the reflection, so cache the result. After all, the type information won't change during execution.

Comment: Won't this yield overridden properties multiple times?

Comment: No, because he said BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly.

Comment: The problem here is that if we re-write our class hierarchy so that B.P overrides A.P, we still get three properties even though an object of type C now only has two.

Comment: In contrast, Yuriy, your answer would yield only two sets of get/setters, which is the correct behavior.

Comment: You're right, I misread what you said. I also tested my method and it does return only two.

Answer (score 3):

Through reflection, the new keyword only hides the inherited property if the signature matches. I guess reflection matches signatures on property accessors (get_ & set_). It's the reasons why `GetProperties()` returns B.P and C.P when the return type differ.

I recently discovered [Fasteflect](http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/) which provides advanced reflection mechanisms.

I checked and Fasteflect `type.Properties` returns all the tree of hidden members (P). I think the API consider backing members (virtual/override) and hidden members (new) differently which is a good thing for your 'problem' ;)

My test with fasterflect :

```
class Class1
{
    public object field1 = null;

    public virtual object Property1 { get; set; }

    public object Property2 { get; set; }

    public string Property3 { get; set; }
}

class Class2 : Class1
{
    public new object field1 = null;

    public override object Property1 { get; set; }

    public new string Property3 { get; set; }
}

class Class3 : Class2
{
    public new string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

Filter backing members but returns all hidden members :

```
typeof(Class3).Properties(Flags.ExcludeBackingMembers | Flags.Public | Flags.Instance)
```

- typeof(Class3).Properties(Flags.ExcludeBackingMembers | Flags.Public | Flags.Instance)    Count = 5   System.Collections.Generic.IList

  - `[0]  {System.String Property3}   System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`
  - `[1]  {System.Object Property1}   System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`
  - `[2]  {System.String Property3}   System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`
  - `[3]  {System.Object Property2}   System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`
  - `[4]  {System.String Property3}   System.Reflection.PropertyInfo`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/51y09td4%28VS.71%29.aspx#vclrfnew_newmodifier : A constant, field, property, or type introduced in a class or struct hides all base class members with the same name.

Comment: Not through reflection. Since properties are accessors, I guess reflection matches signatures on accessor methods (get_ & set_).

Comment: After some testing and inspection of Fasterflect, I can safely say that their answer to this problem is totally equivalent to driis's.  Their recursive solution to finding hidden members is incapable of excluding virtual properties that have been overridden.  (Actually, setting the ExcludeBackingMembers flag somehow excludes all three properties in both cases.)  However, thanks for the link.

Comment: Weird, I added my test in the post. I tested again and ExcludeBackingMembers don't exclude hidden members. I tried without auto properties too : same behavior.

Comment: Interesting - it did work much better with exactly the flags you used.  However, it still failed in my testing.  If you hide an overridden property, it still disappears.  (Add public new object Property1 to your Class3.)  So, in effect, there are still properties there that can be used, but are not visible to reflection.

Comment: Right, really interesting, thanks for this remark. It's because the Property1 in Class1 and Class2 are still backing members. The ExcludeBackingMembers do his job but almost bad since it should return Property1 of Class2 too (which become a hidden member) according to the new modifier in Class3. Maybe advanced querying can handle this : http://fasterflect.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Advanced%20Queries&referringTitle=Getting%20Started

Comment: Hm, In case with: ```public int Prop { get; }``` and ```public float Prop { get; }``` reflection returns two properties. 

But when you have events with different types then reflection returns only one event. 

This all rather looks like a bug.