# Why does GetProperties list a protected property (declared in a generic base class) twice?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

When I declare the following simple classes:

```
class Class1<T>
{
    protected virtual T Prop1 { get; set; }
    protected virtual string Prop2 { get; set; }
}

class Class2 : Class1<string>
{
    protected override string Prop1 { get; set; }
    protected override string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

and now I use Reflection to get the properties of Class2 like this:

```
var hProperties = typeof(Class2).GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

then Prop2 will be listed once while Prop1 will be listed twice! This behaviour seems strange to me. Shouldn't Prop1 and Prop2 be treated as identical??

What can I do to have Prop1 only once in hProperties? I don't want to use BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly as I also want to get other protected properties of Class1 that are not overridden.

Comment: I think it has to do with the override.  The signature of `Prop1` in `Class2` is not identical to that in `Prop1`.  In your example, there's no reason to override `Prop1` at all.

Comment: @Tony: You're right, here there is no reason to override `Prop1`. I tried do find an example as simple as possible. In our code the getters and setters are different so it makes sense to override the property.

Comment: Which .NET version does this happen on? I just ran a quick test on 4.5.1 and I got the expected two results.

Comment: @Jon: Thank you for testing. This happens on .NET version 4.5

Comment: @Jon: Now I created a console application with .NET version 4.5.1 and I still have 3 results. Strange. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @spetry: Assuming the code above is exactly what you tested, what is the value of `Environment.Version` in your app?

Comment: @Jon: 4.0.30319.34014

Comment: @spetry: Actually I did not run your *exact* code earlier; I made the properties `public`. And when you do so, you get back only two results vs three for `protected`. So... smells like a bug.

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715023/property-hiding-and-reflection-c).

Comment: I tried some methods to and got next results https://dotnetfiddle.net/TEkXle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at the compiled assembly's metadata to make sure that the two properties have identical structure apart from the name:

[image]

I'm using ILDASM instead of the usual decompiler tools to make sure that nothing is hidden or displayed in a more friendly way. The two properties are identical apart from the name.

One of the two `Prop1` properties returned is from `Class1` and one of them is from `Class2`.

This appears to be a bug. The bug seems to be that base class members are not correctly added to the results. When `DeclaredOnly` is not specified [all inherited properties should be returned as well](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx).

I'm using DotPeek and the Reflector VS extension that allows to debug decompiled BCL code to debug the reflection code. The behavior seen in this question is triggered in this method:

```
    private void PopulateProperties(RuntimeType.RuntimeTypeCache.Filter filter, RuntimeType declaringType, Dictionary<string, List<RuntimePropertyInfo>> csPropertyInfos, bool[] usedSlots, ref RuntimeType.ListBuilder<RuntimePropertyInfo> list)
    {
      int token = RuntimeTypeHandle.GetToken(declaringType);
      if (MetadataToken.IsNullToken(token))
        return;
      MetadataEnumResult result;
      RuntimeTypeHandle.GetMetadataImport(declaringType).EnumProperties(token, out result);
      RuntimeModule module = RuntimeTypeHandle.GetModule(declaringType);
      int numVirtuals = RuntimeTypeHandle.GetNumVirtuals(declaringType);
      for (int index1 = 0; index1 < result.Length; ++index1)
      {
        int num = result[index1];
        if (filter.RequiresStringComparison())
        {
          if (ModuleHandle.ContainsPropertyMatchingHash(module, num, filter.GetHashToMatch()))
          {
            Utf8String name = declaringType.GetRuntimeModule().MetadataImport.GetName(num);
            if (!filter.Match(name))
              continue;
          }
          else
            continue;
        }
        bool isPrivate;
        RuntimePropertyInfo runtimePropertyInfo = new RuntimePropertyInfo(num, declaringType, this.m_runtimeTypeCache, out isPrivate);
        if (usedSlots != null)
        {
          if (!(declaringType != this.ReflectedType) || !isPrivate)
          {
            MethodInfo methodInfo = runtimePropertyInfo.GetGetMethod();
            if (methodInfo == (MethodInfo) null)
              methodInfo = runtimePropertyInfo.GetSetMethod();
            if (methodInfo != (MethodInfo) null)
            {
              int slot = RuntimeMethodHandle.GetSlot((IRuntimeMethodInfo) methodInfo);
              if (slot < numVirtuals)
              {
                if (!usedSlots[slot])
                  usedSlots[slot] = true;
                else
                  continue;
              }
            }
            if (csPropertyInfos != null)
            {
              string name = runtimePropertyInfo.Name;
              List<RuntimePropertyInfo> list1 = csPropertyInfos.GetValueOrDefault(name);
              if (list1 == null)
              {
                list1 = new List<RuntimePropertyInfo>(1);
                csPropertyInfos[name] = list1;
              }
              for (int index2 = 0; index2 < list1.Count; ++index2)
              {
                if (runtimePropertyInfo.EqualsSig(list1[index2]))
                {
                  list1 = (List<RuntimePropertyInfo>) null;
                  break;
                }
              }
              if (list1 != null)
                list1.Add(runtimePropertyInfo);
              else
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
              bool flag = false;
              for (int index2 = 0; index2 < list.Count; ++index2)
              {
                if (runtimePropertyInfo.EqualsSig(list[index2]))
                {
                  flag = true;
                  break;
                }
              }
              if (flag)
                continue;
            }
          }
          else
            continue;
        }
        list.Add(runtimePropertyInfo);
      }
    }
```

Why does the behavior disappear for public properties?

```
      if (!(declaringType != this.ReflectedType) || !isPrivate)
```

There's a check for that.

`Class1<string>.Prop2` is filtered out here:

```
              bool flag = false;
              for (int index2 = 0; index2 < list.Count; ++index2)
              {
                if (runtimePropertyInfo.EqualsSig(list[index2]))
                {
                  flag = true;
                  break;
                }
              }
              if (flag)
                continue;
```

because `EqualsSig` returns true. It appears that properties are deduplicated by name and by sig if you are asking for private members... I don't know why. Seems deliberate, though.

It is tiring to follow this convoluted code. [This is better and commented.](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/a.html#399ac2aa7ff75c98) I suspect they are removing private properties because you could elevate privileges by inheriting from some class to get all private members of it.

**And here is the answer:**

```
// For backward compatibility, even if the vtable slots don't match, we will still treat
// a property as duplicate if the names and signatures match.
```

So they added a hack for backwards compatibility.

You'll have to add your own processing to get the behavior you want. Maybe, [Fastreflect](https://fasterflect.codeplex.com/) can help.

Comment: I can't see how this would be anything other than a bug. Change all properties to `public` and use `BindingFlags.Public` -- you get only two results.

Comment: Does it count as an inherited property if it's hidden?

Comment: Thank you, this is a really good answer! I already implemented a workaround for this in our code.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `Class1<T>.Prop1` and `Class2.Prop1` are not the same property... in `Class1<T>`, the property is of type `T`, whereas in `Class2` it's of type `string`.

`Class2` is just one realization of the generic class `Class1<T>`, but there might be others... consider this:

```
class Class3 : Class1<int>
{
    protected override int Prop1 { get; set; }
    protected override string Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

If you consider that `Class2.Prop1` is the same property as `Class1<T>.Prop1`, that `Class3.Prop1` is the same property as `Class1<T>.Prop1`, then it follows that `Class2.Prop1` is also the same as `Class3.Prop1`, which clearly doesn't make sense: one is of type `string`, the other of type `int`...

Comment: Why would `Class2.Prop1` be the same as `Class3.Prop1` when `Class2` and `Class3` are not related?

Comment: @Jon, that's my point... they're not the same, but the OP seemed to expect `Class2.Prop1` to be considered the same as `Class1<T>.Prop1`. The example with `Class3` is just here to show that it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Judging from usr's answer... I don't think you can say that. The source mainly considers properties "one and the same" if they occupy the same vtable slot on the type, and while I have absolutely no idea about how and why this is implemented at the CLR level I don't immediately see a reason `Class2.Prop1_get` could not be assigned the same slot as `Class1<string>.Prop1_get`. And there's the confusing back-compat hack whose purpose is not very clear... to me it looks like "the" correct answer would necessarily be complicated and not entirely technical.