# Type.GetProperties does not return non-virtual redefined properties from the base type

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm working on a custom serializer and my edge case tests revealed an interesting issue: `Type.GetProperties` method does not return reintroduced properties from the base class of the same signature. While this is expected for overridden properties, I have to serialize non-virtual base properties.

Consider the following example:

```
public class Base
{
    public int NonvirtualProperty { get; set; } // this property is "lost"
    public virtual int VirtualProperty { get; set; }
    public int BaseOnlyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Derived : Base
{
    public int NonvirtualProperty { get; set; }
    public override int VirtualProperty { get; set; }
    public int DerivedOnlyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The test below demonstrates the issue:

```
foreach (var p in typeof(Derived).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.DeclaringType.Name}.{p.Name}");

// Derived.NonvirtualProperty
// Derived.VirtualProperty
// Derived.DerivedOnlyProperty
// Base.BaseOnlyProperty
```

I would expect also `Base.NonvirtualProperty` in the result.

**Note:** For fields and methods everything works as expected. This is especially interesting for methods because they also can be virtual.

**Note 2:** If property types are different in `Base` and `Derived` the base property appears in the result.

What would be the best and most efficient solution?

My ideas so far (both of them seem too ugly and overcomplicated for handling such an edge case):

- Maybe I could obtain properties of each levels by `DeclaredOnly` binding flag and somehow detect if they are either non-virtual ones or the most derived properties of virtual ones. Is there a clean way to do that?
- Or I could query the methods instead, and check if the returned `get_*`/`set_*` methods are really properties.

Comment: I guess you would need to reflect on the chain of base class(es) to find hidden members. If you don't want to do this yourself (it can be labouriuous to match base class member with derived class members to figure out whether they are hidden or not...), 3rd-party libraries (like Fasterflec: https://github.com/buunguyen/fasterflect) might help. (Hope you are aware of possible side-effects of member hiding).

Answer (score 0):

Imho there is no way to get hidden base properties by just reflecting the derived type. Traversing up the inheritance chain should do the trick.

EDIT: The question seems quite similar to [Property hiding and reflection (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715023/property-hiding-and-reflection-c)
There is also a nice example on how to do that traversal with not much Code, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2715286/7895292

Comment: Ah ok, so it was a duplicate after all. I really tried to find another post with the same issue. :) Though the accepted answer there is not too elegant, IMHO. But if there is no better way I have go with something similar.

Answer (score -1):

Thats because the `Derived.NonvirtualProperty` hides the `Base.NonvirtualProperty`. Like the compiler will say. It will suggests *"use the new keyword if hiding was intended"*

---

The prove that it is not directly accessible:

```
var d = new Derived();

var b = (Base)d;

b.NonvirtualProperty =10;

Console.WriteLine($"{d.NonvirtualProperty}");
```

Gives `0`

Comment: I can add the `new` keyword to suppress the compiler warning but that does not solve the issue. And the same works for methods regardless of suppressing the compiler warning. And if I reflect 3rd party types I will never know if the original source code had a `new` keyword.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: This proves it is not lost but both properties exist and you can access both depending on the cast. But the same applies also for methods where there is no such problem.

Comment: If you don't want to lose 'properties' don't hide them

Comment: As I stated this is just an intended edge case scenario. Of course I would not create such classes in a productive code but as a test this is an important scenario for my serializer as I must handle conflicting field and property names.

Comment: So the answer is not wrong but does not forfill your needs

Comment: Actually I can agree with the downvoter as the answer literally says _Thats because the Derived.NonvirtualProperty hides the Base.NonvirtualProperty_ - however, this is incorrect: you can hide a field and a method the same way, `GetFields` and `GetMethods` still return the hidden members as well. Only `GetProperties` fails to return them. Feel free to check here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eALFeD - just replace `GetProperties` by `GetMethods`: the accessor methods of the nonvirtual hidden property are returned. And after all that's my solution, too.

Comment: If that is correct, the reflection is incosititent. And my answer is not complete. I've tested it with properties but not with fields/methods.